# Need Clarification About toString() Method with getSelection()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to log the string value of the user selection object

My question is why it doesn't work in the code examples below? it should.. logically

NOTE: I'm using chrome.

```
//THIS CODE DOESN'T LOG THE SELECTED TEXT, IT LOGS NOTHING
var selobj = document.getSelection();
var selobjstg = selobj.toString();
btn.onmousedown = function(){
console.log(selobjstg); 
}
  
//THIS CODE ALSO DOESN'T LOG THE SELECTED TEXT
var selobj = document.getSelection().toString();
btn.onmousedown = function(){
console.log(selobj); 
}

// THIS DOES   
var selobj = document.getSelection();
btn.onmousedown = function(){
console.log(selobj.toString()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the event's scope, as mentioned above. This would also work:

```
btn.onmousedown = function(){
  let selobj = document.getSelection();
  let selobjstg = selobj.toString();
  console.log(selobjstg); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, After spending the whole day now there is a way :)

Answer (score 2):

In this code `selobjstg` variable looks at the `string` value of the selection way before `mousedown` event happens.

```
var selobj = document.getSelection();
var selobjstg = selobj.toString();
btn.onmousedown = function(){
console.log(selobjstg); 
}
```

In this code now `selobj` variable looks at the `string` value of the selection way before `mousedown` event happens.

```
var selobj = document.getSelection().toString();
btn.onmousedown = function(){
console.log(selobj); 
}
```

However, in this code `string` value is detected just after the `mousedown` event happens.

```
var selobj = document.getSelection();
btn.onmousedown = function(){
console.log(selobj.toString()); 
}
```